# complex constexpr alternatives

Tags: templates, visual-c++, c++14

Consider

```
typedef std::complex<double> Complex;
Complex ComplexExpresion(int a) {return Complex(0,-a);}
```

Since one cannot write

```
template<typename D>    
struct A
{
  static constexpr Complex value = ComplexExpresion(D::value);
};
```

as an alternative one writes

```
template<typename D> 
struct B
{
  static const Complex value; 
};

template<typename D> 
const Complex B<D>::value = ComplexExpresion(D::value);
```

Consider now

```
template<typename D, int N> 
struct C;

template<typename D> 
struct C<D,1>
{
  static const Complex value; 
};

template<typename D> 
const Complex C<D,1>::value = B<D>::value;
```

For some reasone

```
struct Data
{
    static auto constexpr value =2;
};

int main()
{
        using C = C<Data,1>;

        std::cout << C::value;
}
```

prints the correct value(which is (0,-2) ) [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a0168072a98cae49) but the same code prints (0,0) when complied by MSVC++

I have 2 questions

1) why it is so on MSVC++ and is there known workaround?

2) is there better alternative for `struct A` than `struct B` which is not exactly the same thing...

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio?

Comment: I'm running 2015 comunity

Comment: pasted your coliru code directly into visual studio 2015 community and got the expected results (0,-2). can you verify by re-pasting and re-running.

Comment: oh weird, I get (0,0) in debug mode, and (0,-2) in release mode

Comment: good point, i mean debug/release...

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a compiler bug unless I'm missing something. This isn't really an answer, just sharing what I found. This is the smallest example I could deduce that exhibits the issue:

```
#include <iostream>

// using function is important
int func() { return 1; }

// template is imporant
template<class D>
struct B
{
  static const int value;
};

// defined outside block is important
template<class D>
const int B<D>::value = func();

// going through C is important
struct C
{
  static const int value;
};

const int C::value = B<int>::value;

int main()
{
  // should print 1 but prints 0
  std::cout << C::value << std::endl;
}
```

surprisingly this also trips up clang unless I specify func as `constexpr` or specify `-stdlib=libc++` (at least on [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ee7487034b4eb56d))

I guess you can fix your issue by skipping one of the bits above. You can do `static constexpr Complex value = ComplexExpresion(D::value);` if you mark ComplexEspression as `constexpr`.

Comment: i didn't try it as a function yet (in my real code I just write the expression in the structure definition), but it looks like expression in complex numbers cannot be constexpr. I can put something like Complex value =1.0i, but not Complex value =-1.0i.

Comment: just tried making the function constexpr on coliru, 
    `template<typename D>    
 struct A
    {
      static constexpr Complex value = ComplexExpresion(D::value);
     };` and `std::cout << A<Data>::value;` in main it says `undefined reference to A<Data>::value`